# iOS 8 Today Extension not working on iPhone 6 and 6+ devices

Tags: ios, ios8, iphone-6

I currently have a simple Today Extension that loads an Image and some text. It is loading great on all other devices besides iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ I am seeing the extension in the today section its just collapsed and loads no data. The logs are not telling me anything. Has anyone had this problem recently with iPhone 6 or iPhone 6+ devices. NOT THE SIMULATOR

I also keep getting this when running the extension on my device

[image: Error Message from Xcode 6.0.1]

Comment: The sample project from my tutorial works fine on my iPhone 6. Maybe it can shed some light. http://www.raywenderlich.com/83809/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial

Comment: Argh! I wasn't using arm64 in valid architectures. Solved thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the valid architectures in your widget build settings and update the one "armv64" and change it to "arm64". It will work.

Comment: I was having the same issue. I just tried it and it worked. You saved my day man!